# Why prefer use of CSS pseudo class to apply background image instead of directly applying to the element?

Tags: css, sass, frontend, web-frontend

I was going through different video tutorials and a few suggested to use `::before` pseudo selector to apply background image.

Is there any specific reason to follow this trend?

Comment: Please either share video link or more details

Comment: @SawanPatodia, Please find the link : 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KVrdL0VcAk&list=PLu0W_9lII9agiCUZYRsvtGTXdxkzPyItg&index=39

Comment: This is in Hindi and the person is talking about pseudo selector at 24:00.

Answer (score 1):

It is really a personal preference. Using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements in this case allows you to insert images without the need for adding extra html elements.

[Here is an example by Bryan Robinson of its clever usage](https://bryanlrobinson.com/blog/how-to-css-after-elements-for-background-overlays/)

You can see how it can be used to create a three layered image background with just a single html element.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now it's usage quite a bit.